# Python to submit keyword search to Salesforce for results

Tags: python, salesforce

What would be the proper way to submit search keyword to Salesforce.com and retrieve the search results?

For example, manually with salesforce.com opened in browser, I can key in "manufacturer" in the search box on top of the Salesforce page. That returns all results in different categories like Leads, Accounts, People, Opportunities, Activities etc.

Here, I want to search a keyword "manufacturer", and retrieve the **Opportunity Name, URL, Stage, Created Date** in the category "**Opportunities**".

simple-salesforce documentation provides an example, but I don't really understand:

```
sf.query("SELECT Id, Email FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Jones'")
```

What would be the Python way to submit such searches and return retrievable results including contents, url and dates etc?

Answer (score 1):

The example provided uses [SOQL/SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm) for queries, which is what you'll need to use as well if you intend to use the api. In python, you can use `urlib.request` to send a request with your query to the specified url.

```py
from urllib import request

url = # PUT URL HERE - /vXX.X/search/?q=SOSL search string
response = request.Request(url)
```

You can now read the response using `json` module and fetch the info you want.

- [REST API URL Structure](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search.htm)
- [Executing search query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)

Unfortunately you did not provide exactly what you want to do, so I cannot provide a full code example

Comment: thanks! can you please provide an example, that to search a keyword "manufacturer", and retrieve the Opportunity Name, URL, Stage, Created Date in the category "Opportunities"?

Comment: @MarkK the SOSL syntax for it would be something like `FIND {manufacturer}
RETURNING Opportunity(Id, Name, StageName, CloseDate)`. You experiment with them in SF Developer Console. If the 1st link Chase gave you is too much to go through - consider the trailhead course? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database/apex_database_sosl